# How do I redirect multiple urls to same url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how do I redirect multiple url to another one url
I have tried but its not working

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.to/q1$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.to/q2$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.to/q3$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.to/q4$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.to/q5$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sub.domain.to/full-q [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

ok it worked when I added `%{REQUEST_URI}`

so this worked

```
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^sub\.domain\.to/q1$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^sub\.domain\.to/q2$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^sub\.domain\.to/q3$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^sub\.domain\.to/q4$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond  %{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} ^sub\.domain\.to/q5$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sub.domain.to/full-q [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

The `HTTP_HOST` server variable contains the value of the `Host` HTTP request header, ie. the hostname only. This does not contain the URL-path (ie. `/q1` and `/q2` in your example).

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path.

Try the following instead:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.to [NC]
RewriteRule ^(q1|q2|q3|q4|q5)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/full-q [NC,R=301,L]
```

Or, use the `REQUEST_URI` server variable in a *condition*, which contains the full URL-path. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.to [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/q1$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/q2$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/q3$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/q4$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/q5$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/full-q [R=301,L]
```

Test with a 302 (temporary) redirect to avoid potential caching issues and only change to a 301 (permanent) redirect - if that is the intention - once you have confirmed this works as intended.

You will need to clear your browser cache before testing.